# how to use Switch instead of if else if

Tags: java

Hi Folks new to programming...is it possible to change this to a switch statement instead of if else if....if so please point me in the right direction

int dir = get_dir();

```
    if (dir == 0) //  facing north (up)
        {
        setX(x); //  goes to x position
        setY(y - 1); //  goes to y -1 position
        } 
    else if (dir == 1) //  facing east (right)
        {
        setX(x - 1); //  goes to x -1 position
        setY(y); //  goes to y position
        } 
    else if (dir == 2) // facing south (down)
        {
        setX(x); //  goes to x position
        setY(y - 1); // goes to y -1 position
        } 
    else if (dir == 3) // facing west (left)
        {
        setX(x - 1); //  goes to x -1 position
        setY(y); //  goes to y position
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can use constants instead of magic numbers like SOUTH = 2..

Comment: You're halfway there. Step one: Know about switch-case. Step two: implement it.

Comment: You could simplify your if statements. If `dir == 0` or `dir == 2`, you're doing the same thing. Same for `1` and `3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all the `if` and `else if` and put them inside `switch(dir) { }`.
E.g change the

```
`else if (dir == 3)`
```

with

```
case 3 :  
     your code;
     break;
```

and put them inside `switch(dir) { }` block.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, of course.  You just need to create a separate case for each of the if statements you are trying to combine:

```
int dir = get_dir();

switch(dir){

case 0:               //  facing north (up)
    setX(x);          //  goes to x position
    setY(y - 1);      //  goes to y -1 position
    break;

case 1:               //  facing east (right)
    setX(x - 1);      //  goes to x -1 position
    setY(y);          //  goes to y position
    break;

case 2:               // facing south (down)
    setX(x);          //  goes to x position
    setY(y - 1);      // goes to y -1 position
    break;

case 3:               // facing west (left)
    setX(x - 1);      //  goes to x -1 position
    setY(y);          //  goes to y position
    break;
}
```

As others have already remarked, you can also create a default case to handle options that are not 0-3.  In addition, you could enumerate those directions or create constant values to enhance readability.

Comment: Just to add to that, you can include a `default:` case at the end , to prompt an invalid `dir` . `default:` is matched when none of the other switches find a match.

Comment: Thank you I tried various ways and just kept getting faults

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `enum`s to switch on the directions, and this might be a more readable and more type-safe way, i.e. you won't mix your direction with some other integer value:

```
enum Direction {NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Direction dir = Direction.EAST;

    switch(dir){
        case NORTH:
            setX(x);     //  goes to x position
            setY(y - 1); //  goes to y -1 position
            break;
        case WEST:
            setX(x - 1); //  goes to x -1 position
            setY(y);     //  goes to y position
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I second the usage of enums, integer constants are evil!